# A programmatic way to discover the number of CPUs and spec for each CPU/Core in Ubuntu Karmic?

Tags: linux, hardware, cpu, system-administration, specifications

A programmatic way to discover the number of CPUs and spec for each CPU/Core in Ubuntu Karmic? Bash or C/C++, Python, Perl are fine. Thanks!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
cat /proc/cpuinfo
```

Answer (score 2):

you can try `lshw` if you have it. Other useful tools include `lspci`, `lshal`, `biosdecode` etc. also try `/proc/cpuinfo` and others at `/proc`

@OP
/proc/cpuinfo is just a normal file, so you can use any tools that can display file info to view it (besides cat. cat is used for concatenating files by the way)

```
$ more /proc/cpuinfo
$ awk '{print}' /proc/cpuinfo
$ while read -r line; do echo $line;done < /proc/cpuinfo
```

Comment: you can use other tools such as `more`, `awk` or even the `bash` shell to display `/proc/cpuinfo`. Its just a file.